# Illegal string offset 'formid'

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

On main page of MODx site with snippet code

```
[!eForm? 
    &formid=`forma_bron` 
    &tpl=`forma_bron` 
    &to=`example@example.com`
    &report=`report-tpl` 
    &subject=`Request`  
    &eFormOnBeforeMailSent=`send`
!]
```

I get error:

> Illegal string offset 'formid'
>
> File :    /home/users/account/domains/site/assets/snippets/eform/eform.inc.php
>
> Line :    104
>
> Source :  $validFormId = ($formid==$_POST['formid'])?1:0;

Here is check on POST parameter although I call GET request when I try open main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form handled by eForm on that page needs a hidden input with `name="formid"` and `value="forma_bron"`.

But since this is happening during a GET request, you have to change following code in eform.inc.php (around line 105)

```
$validFormId = ($formid==$_POST['formid'])?1:0;
```

to

```
$validFormId = (isset($_POST['formid']) && $formid == $_POST['formid']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: 1. How to add this input to the form?
2. How this value will be in POST array on GET request?

Comment: I have extended my answer. I hope this is the only PHP notice issue in eForm. 

You should set the 'Detection level of PHP errors' in Tools > Configuration > User to 'Detect all errors except E_NOTICE' or less, to avoid MODX stopping on those 'warnings'.

Comment: Yes, the eForm code is quite old and seems not check for i.e. not existing array keys.